# Start with soap ui

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, api

> I want to do API testing in my project. I installed soap ui for api
>   testing. I don't know to get start using soap ui. Can anybody help me
>   to start doing soap ui testing . Is we have to write automation code
>   in soap ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `soapui` Support only `Groovy` or `JavaScript`.

Read below blog Very short summarized

[Getting Started](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/10-tips-for-the-soapui-beginner.html)

[SoapUi](https://stanfy.com/blog/madcode-meetup-how-to-test-web-api-using-soapui/)

Comment: I have a rest project to test with soap ui and I know the java program language. is saopui support java lanaguage.? How  to start doing automation coding with my project ?

Comment: No it's only support scripting language. Open the above link. It will help you to start

Comment: Raithore Does support ruby or python ?   both are scripting language

Comment: I want to perform automation for entering different values as parametres  how ?

Comment: @Sagar007   Is it possible to add plugin saop ui with eclipse or idea intellij tool ? I want to perform web api testing.  I just installed soap ui. And I could'nt find any idea about the soapui..